# How to alternate alternating negatives in a series (summation)?

Tags: summation, mathematica

*Note: while this isn't a strictly Mathematica, I am using it to find my results.*

I have a problem where I integrate

```
E^x x^n
```

and I'm given results like

```
E^x (720 - 720 x + 360 x^2 - 120 x^3 + 30 x^4 - 6 x^5 + x^6)
E^x (-120 + 120 x - 60 x^2 + 20 x^3 - 5 x^4 + x^5)
E^x (24 - 24 x + 12 x^2 - 4 x^3 + x^4)
```

where n = 6, 5, and 4, respectively.

For an assignment, I need to find a summation in which I can input an n and it gives me those results correctly. My issue is with the alternating alternative negatives though, since they are not constant with each degree. I've gotten this close:

```
e[x_, n_] := (E^x )*Sum[((n!/i!)*(x^i))*(-1)^(1 - i), {i, 0, n}]
```

(also:)[image]

and it gives me these answers

```
E^x (-720 + 720 x - 360 x^2 + 120 x^3 - 30 x^4 + 6 x^5 - x^6)
E^x (-120 + 120 x - 60 x^2 + 20 x^3 - 5 x^4 + x^5)
E^x (-24 + 24 x - 12 x^2 + 4 x^3 - x^4)
```

for n = 6, 5, and 4 once again, but now the even n's are not alternating right.

Perhaps its just something little that I'm missing, but I can't seem t figure out how to alternate alternating signs between odd and even n's.

Any help with this would be appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is it as simple as throwing in  a factor of $(-1)^n$? I guess that would change your factor to $(-1)^{1-i+n}$, right?

Comment: @MPW Jeez, wow you're right... I knew it was gonna be something small. I feel like i tried to do everything except that haha, thanks. It actually ended up just being to the i+n

Comment: I'll convert the comment to an answer then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*[Comment converted to answer]* Is it as simple as throwing in a factor of $(-1)^n$? I guess that would change your factor to $(-1)^{1-i+n}$, right?